# Integrable systems and Lagrangian fibrations

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry, fibration, integrable-systems

It is known that every integrable system gives rise to a Lagrangian fibration via action-angle variables. My question is how to tell if a given Lagrangian fibration is an integrable system, that is has global action-angle variables. Are there any invariants one can compute which would tell one that a given Lagrangian fibration is in fact an integrable system? Are there at least some known obstructions for Lagrangian fibrations to be integrable systems? That is, I want to characterize integrable systems from among Lagrangian vibrations.

Comment: Have you looked at Duistermaat's paper *On Global Action-Angle Coordinates* and the works that followed it? These are some nice notes by Daniele Sepe:  https://www.math.tecnico.ulisboa.pt/~jmourao/inves/D_Sepe_Lagrangian_Fibrations.pdf

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will look more into the sources you suggested.